# syntax question in R model specification

Tags: r, model, regression, plyr

Looking at the plyr tutorial, I find the following
preparation :

```
b2 <- ddply(baseball, "id", transform, cyear = year - min(year) + 1)  
b2 <- ddply(b2, "id", transform, career = (cyear - 1) / max(cyear)) 
bruth <- subset(b2, id == "ruthba01")
# Could we model that as two straight lines?
bruth$p <- (bruth$career - 0.5) * 100
```

now some model

```
mod <- lm(g ~ p + p:I(p > 0), data = bruth)
```

what is the difference with ?

```
mod <- lm(g ~ p + I(p > 0), data = bruth)
```

when I check

```
mod$model
```

in both cases it yields the same columns with the same numbers.
yet the regression coefficients are entirely different...

any idea of what this notation means ?

Comment: check `model.matrix(mod)` for both models and you will find the difference.

Comment: @nicolas or @Ramnath could go ahead and post the answer (different parameterization) as a real answer ... I posted a similar response recently on the r-sig-mixed-models list: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel/6351

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code to see the impact of the different models:

```
 with(bruth, plot(p, predict(mod), type="l" )  )
 with(bruth, points(p, g,  col="red") )
 with(bruth, lines(p, predict(mod2), lty=3, lwd=2, col="red") )
 title(main="Different uses of I() and interaction")
```

It highlights the impact of the choice of (arbitrary?) joinpoints on the output of segmented regression.

[image]